# Since when are the images in the asset catalog shown that small?

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7, assets

maybe it is an Xcode 7.3.1 bug but since when are the preview images in the asset folder rendered that small that I have to zoom or preview manually which icon is currently set.

I have added a screenshot to show the problem.

Someone else noticed this behavior and has a solution for this because its a bit annoying.

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding a new image set with a different image?

Comment: Yes already tried - also new asset catalog